# How is the wave function for a particle affected, when the particle is near lightspeed?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, wavefunction, speed-of-light, schroedinger-equation

Apologies in advance. I'm new to QM, but find it extremely interesting.
I thought it to be interesting, to see if a particle, subject to quantum mechanics, would still behave so, if the mass becomes classical. And so, I thought of a particle near light speed. I understand that the double derivative of the wave function (the curvature) becomes extremely small. Does this mean that the particle's probability is spread out over huge distances?
Here is a small sketch I made:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the physics stackexchange ! We would strongly recommend to use MathJax for writing of the equations.

Answer (score 1):

Schroedinger's equation is based on the non-relativistic dispersion relation

$$E = \frac{(\hbar k)^2}{2m}$$

where $E$ is the energy, $\vec{k}$ the wave vector and $m$ the rest mass of the particle. If one goes to relativistic particles one has to use another dispersion relation:

$$E =\pm \sqrt{(\hbar k)^2 c^2 + m^2 c^4}$$

In different words, the Schroedinger equation is no longer valid in this regime. So one better uses the Klein-Gordon equation for spin-less particles or better for spin-half particles as electrons the Dirac-equation:
$$(i\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu + m)\psi =0$$

which is partial-differential matrix equation as $\gamma^\mu$ are 4x4-matrices..